# Defining a list of lists in SageMath

Tags: sage

In SageMath, I want to define a list whose elements are lists with two elements.

I tried to do it by appending elements to the inner lists,
accessed by their index in the outer list:

```
K=GF(3)

InitialStateSet=[]

c=0
for i in K:
    for j in K:
        if (i,j)!=(0,0):
            InitialStateSet[c].append(i)
            InitialStateSet[c].append(j)
        c+=1
print(InitialStateSet)
```

Comment: Please provide more information. In particular, what is your desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
sage: K=GF(3)
sage: InitialStateSet=[]
sage: for i in K:
....:     for j in K:
....:         if (i,j)!=(0,0):
....:             InitialStateSet.append([i,j])
....: 
sage: InitialStateSet
[[0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2]]
```

Or somewhat more compactly:

```
sage: K=GF(3)
sage: InitialStateSet=[[i,j] for i in K for j in K]
```

Answer (score 1):

To stay close to your initial code, one could write:

```py
K = GF(3)
states = []

c = 0
for i in K:
    for j in K:
        if (i, j) != (0, 0):
            states.append([])
            states[c].append(i)
            states[c].append(j)
            c += 1
print(states)
```

Output:

```
[[0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2]]
```

Alternatively, one could use a vector space over the field `K`,
and, as John Palmieri suggests, list comprehension, with an extra
`if` to only get nonzero vectors:

```py
K = GF(3)
V = K^2
states = [v for v in V if v]
```

or if `K` and `V` are only used here, this could be done in one line:

```py
states = [v for v in GF(3)^2 if v]
```

Then we would get:

```py
sage: print(states)
[(1, 0), (2, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 2)]
```

Comment: You're right, thank you for the correction: my list comprehension version missed the nonzero criterion.